# Css files not working another component in Angular

Tags: html, angular, sass, components

the css rules I created for `header` and `sidenav` do not work when I use it in the `dashboard` component, where do I make a mistake?

header.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row class="justify-content-between">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSidebar()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <div class="row mr-2 ml-auto">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="user mt-2 d-flex align-items-center">
            UserName
            <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item>
              <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
              Logout
            </button>
          </mat-menu>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() toggleSidebarForme : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleSidebar() {
    this.toggleSidebarForme.emit();
  }

}
```

header.component.scss

```
mat-toolbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

ul{
  li{
    list-style: none;
  }
}

button{
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
}


::ng-deep {
  .mat-menu-content {
    width: 160px;
  }
}
```

sidenav.component.html

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <h2 matSubheader class="mt-2">Applications</h2>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="list-item-activate" href=""><mat-icon>dashboard</mat-icon>Dashboard</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="list-item-activate" href=""><mat-icon>supervised_user_circle</mat-icon>Users</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="list-item-activate" href=""><mat-icon>compare_arrows</mat-icon>Link 2</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="list-item-activate" href=""><mat-icon>verified_user</mat-icon>Link 3</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

sidenav.component.scss

```
.mat-divider {
  border-top-width: 2px;

}

.mat-icon {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}

.mat-list-item {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  ::ng-deep{
    .mat-list-item-content {
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 0 8px;
      &:hover {
        background: #32325c;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
    }
  }

}

.list-item-active {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-list-item-content {
      background: #32325c;
      &:hover {
        background: #32325c;
      }
    }
  }
}

.mat-subheader {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

sidenav.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggedIn$ : Observable<boolean> | undefined;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {



  }

}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
<app-header></app-header>
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

According to the css rules here, the `sidenav` background should not be white, but when I use the `sidenav` component in the `dashboard` component, the background comes up as white. How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .selector { ... }
```

must not be nested inside any CSS. Just try to see if you can remove all the ::ng-deep CSS defs outside any other CSS definition and check if that is working

WRONG:

```
    .parent {
       ...
       ::ng-deep .child {
          ...
       }
}
```

CORRECT:

```
    ::ng-deep .parent {
       ...
       .child {
          ...
       }
}
```